# Is Wiki right about de Bruijn graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

On the wiki page of [de Bruijn Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph), it claims the set of Edges is:

$$ E = \{((v_1,v_2,...,v_n), (v_2,...,v_n,s_i)): i = 1, ..., m\} $$

but shouldn't it be

$$ E = \{((s_1,s_2,...,s_n), (s_2,...,s_n,s_i)): i = 1, ..., m\} $$

If $v$ is $(s_i, s_j, ..., s_k)$, then wouldn't the definition that "one of the vertices can be expressed as another vertex by shifting all of it's symbols by one place to the left and adding a new symbol at the end of this vertex" insinuate that the first definition of the edge set is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

The intent is that $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ can be any symbol belonging to $S$.  That is, a word $v_1v_2 \ldots v_n$ is linked to every word that begins by $v_2v_3 \ldots v_n$.  That's what the definition expresses.

Though it could be made clear that $v_1, \ldots, v_n \in S$.
You could extend the definition by writing

$$
E = \{((v_1, \ldots, v_n), (v_2, \ldots, v_n, s_i)) : 1 \leq i \leq m \mbox{ and } v_1, \ldots, v_n \in S \}
$$

If you define it as $E = \{((s_1, \ldots, s_n), (s_2, \ldots, s_n, s_i)) : i = 1,\ldots, m\}$, then you are just defining the edge going from the particular word $s_1s_2 \ldots s_n$.  The wiki definition makes it applicable to every word by using the $v_i$ variables instead.

Comment: I was under the impression that $v_i = (s_{i_1}, s_{i_2}, ... , s_{i_n})$, so that $s_i$ cannot be interpreted as $v$, but that $v$ was only a sequences of $\{s_i\}$. According to my definition of $v_i$, I defined $f( v_i, s_j ) = (s_{i_2}, s_{i_3}, ..., s_{i_n}, s_j)$ in which case $E = \{ ( v_i, f(v_i, j) )\}$

Comment: In the wiki definition, $v_i$ is just a single symbol.  But yes, you could define it as you do (though it's $f(v_i, j)$ instead of $f(v_i, s_j)$ and in $E$, you need to specify that $1 \leq j \leq m$ - and ideally specify the range of values that $v_i$ takes).  Except that it makes it more complicated than it need to be in my opinion.  But hey, as long as it fits the definition: there is an edge from $w_1$ to $w_2$ if the last $n - 1$ symbols of $w_1$ are the first $n - 1$ symbols of $w_2$.

Comment: Thanks, you're right about $j$ instead of $s_j$. I think I still am having trouble seeing that it's possible for $v_i$ to take on a value of $s_j$. I thought this was only possible for the cast of $n=1$. The very definition of $V$ on the wiki page shows that it is an ordered subset of $S$ where $S$ is a symbol. So in the definition of $E$ on the page, $v_i$ is going to be a sequence of from $S$. Not trying to be problematic here - just not understanding.

Comment: Yes, I think it might be easier to grasp the intuition first, and then see how they made it formal.  You can view de Brujin graph as relationships between words.  $S$ is the alphabet, i.e. the set of letters that you are given to make words.  $s_1$ is the first letter, $s_2$ is the second letter, and so on.  $V$ is just the set of all possible words.  If it helps, just try with $S = \{a, b, c\}$.  Then $V$ will be $aaa, aab, aac, aba, \ldots, ccc$.  Then, to make the definition general and extendable to arbitrary alphabets, put $S = \{s_1, \ldots, s_n\}$ and apply the same reasoning.